Camel Karaf Blueprint deploy hangs after restarting windows karaf service and fresh code deploy
We're running karaf 4.4.6 and camel 4.7.0.
We have an issue deploying a blueprint in the following circumstance:

Deploy your code bundles and a blueprint bundle
Stop and start the karaf windows service (without undeploying)
Redeploy your code bundles
Now finally redeploy your blueprint file

Here's the karaf.log.  The Camel blueprint deployment hangs at the last line of this karaf.log snippet:
2024-10-28T14:42:42,831 | INFO  | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | fileinstall | 18 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.7.4 | Installing bundle my.model / 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
2024-10-28T14:42:42,926 | INFO  | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | fileinstall | 18 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.7.4 | Started bundle: file:/E:/karaf-4.4.6/deploy/model-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2024-10-28T14:42:48,840 | INFO  | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | fileinstall | 18 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.7.4 | Installing bundle service / 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
2024-10-28T14:42:54,408 | INFO  | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | fileinstall | 18 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.7.4 | Started bundle: wrap:file:/E:/karaf-4.4.6/deploy/service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=service&Bundle-Version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
2024-10-28T14:43:14,837 | INFO  | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | fileinstall | 18 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.7.4 | Installing bundle my-blueprint.xml / 0.0.0

It hangs forever here ^^ in karaf.log, never giving any additional information and blueprint never finishes deploying.
Any advice or guidance on how to debug this problem?
----- edit Oct 30
After increasing the logging level to DEBUG in our karaf, the last few things that happen before the deploy hangs is this:
2024-10-29T12:43:56,646 | DEBUG | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Tracking service references: [#recipe-41]
2024-10-29T12:43:56,646 | DEBUG | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Instantiating component .camelBlueprint.factory.<oneOfOurBlueprints>
2024-10-29T12:43:56,649 | DEBUG | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Instantiating component blueprintBundle
2024-10-29T12:43:56,652 | DEBUG | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | BlueprintExtender      | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Scanning bundle cdm-service/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT for blueprint application
2024-10-29T12:43:56,653 | DEBUG | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | BlueprintExtender      | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | No blueprint application found in bundle service/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
2024-10-29T12:43:56,654 | DEBUG | fileinstall-E:\karaf-4.4.6/deploy | configurator           |  13 - org.apache.felix.configurator -   1.0.16 | Adding bundle service:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT (295) : starting

So it looks like it's hanging as it tries to re-add our service code bundle.
Looking in the karaf CLI with client.bat, the service and blueprint bundles are stuck in 'Starting' state:
303 │ Active   │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT     │ model
304 │ Starting │  80 │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT     │ service
305 │ Starting │  80 │ 0.0.0              │ <oneOfOurBlueprints>.xml
admin@root()>

Once in this state, it also hangs trying to stop the windows karaf service.
I have to kill the karaf java process from task manager.
Here's the last few lines in karaf.log as it tries to stop the the karaf service before hanging:
2024-10-30T10:22:43,686 | INFO  | Karaf Shutdown Socket Thread | ShutdownSocketThread |   4 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 2.2.7 | Karaf shutdown socket: received shutdown command. Stopping framework...
2024-10-30T10:22:43,706 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Stopping blueprint extender...
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Usage for bundle org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm/1.3.2 is 5
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Usage for bundle <oneOfOurblueprints>.xml/0.0.0 is 0
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Usage for bundle org.apache.aries.blueprint.core/1.10.3 is 9
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Usage for bundle camel-blueprint/4.7.0 is 1
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Selected bundles [<oneOfOurBlueprints>.xml/0.0.0] for destroy (no services in use)
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Starting container destruction process for blueprint bundle <oneOfOurBlueprints>.xml/0.0.0
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Scheduling container destruction for blueprint bundle <oneOfOurBlueprints>.xml/0.0.0.
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | DEBUG | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Waiting for container destruction for blueprint bundle <oneOfOurBlueprints>.xml/0.0.0.
2024-10-30T10:22:43,722 | INFO  | FelixShutdown    | BlueprintExtender                | 112 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Destroying container for blueprint bundle <oneOfOurBlueprints>.xml/0.0.0

Once I kill karaf in task manager and restart the karaf windows service, all is well again.  The blueprint deploys on startup, and other blueprints deploy without hanging.
Also, it doesn't matter if I run karaf as a windows service, or run the karaf.bat manually.  It shows the same behavior either way.
Finally, the only somewhat related issue I've found on this is this very old post from 2013:
Karaf blueprint locked on startup with stopping bundles
Any advice on what to try so karaf doesn't hang in these circumstances?
